# How to address a specific UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a static cell layout in a UITableView. During the workflow I need to address the attributes of a specific cell. All cells have an identifier but i did not found a way to actually address the cell using the identifier.

Thanks,
em

Comment: There is no code yet. At the moment I use  UITableViewCell* cell = [detailTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];  which is not reliable in my case.

Comment: Can you explain why `UITableViewCell* cell = [detailTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` is not reliable?

Comment: It is an "unoffical" app and the layout changes a lot, this means I need to adjust the indexPath every time I add/remove cells. Therefor I was hoping to find a solution around the use of the Identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not reliable is probably this (from the documentation):

> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

If you ask for a cell that is not visible on screen, it may have been purged from the table view.

Since you mention that you use a static cell layout in your tableview (I assume you don't rely on cell reuse), you could consider keeping the cells as private properties:

In the private interface:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyTableViewCellClass *myStaticCell;

@end
```

In the implementation:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    MyTableViewCellClass* _myStaticCell;
}

- (MyTableViewCellClass*) myStaticCell {
    if (!_myStaticCell) {
        // Initialize _myStaticCell
    }
    return _myStaticCell
}
```

You can then call this lazy loaded property when `tableView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`is called and whenever you need to modify it.

Note that this approach is only recommended if you have a tableview with static content and don't rely on cell reuse.

Comment: Thanks, actually I try to avoid this way since I do not want a custom class for every single cell. The idea was to use the identifier

Comment: It works with UITableViewCell as well. Doesn't need to be a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Here indexPathSelected is the selected specific cell

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathSelected inSection:0]];
 indexPathSelected           = indexPath.row;

}
```